# how to read recurring events from outlook pst file using libpst

Tags: java, outlook, pst, java-libpst

I'm using the java libpst 0.9.3 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.pff/java-libpst/0.9.3) to read calendar events from a local outlook pst file.
I struggle to get the proper information for recurring appopintments incl. exceptions.

When scanning the appointments, I use

myAppointment.getRecurrenceType()!= 0

to check whether this is an recurring event and then try to use the class

```
PSTAppointmentRecurrence(byte[] recurrencePattern,
                        PSTAppointment appt,
                        PSTTimeZone tz)
```

to create a recurrend appointment object but I fail to create an instance of this class.

I tried this:
myRecurrendAppointment= new PSTAppointmentRecurrence(myAppointment.getRecurrenceStructure(), myAppointment, ???)

??? tz= where do I get the system timezone as an instance of PSTTimeZone?

thanks in advance
Chris

Comment: Could you use `myAppointment.getRecurrenceTimeZone()`? I've been reading through libpst's source code, and [this](https://github.com/rjohnsondev/java-libpst/blob/bf4b8bd327ff78de2aaa8142216acb71d402a2c4/src/test/java/com/pff/AppointmentTest.java#L32) seems to be the only example of creating a `PSTAppointmentRecurrence` object.

Comment: yep that's it - I somehow have read over this method!
tnx for ur support